# How to reference 2 weeks - 1 day within DATEADD() function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a dataset which shows currency spot rates on associated business days and would like to pull values for the 10 most recent data points prior to and including a reference date for EACH currency.

Data looks as follows:

```
AsOfDate    Currency    ExchangeRateUSD
9/11/1997   AED -1
9/11/1997   AUD 1.389178
9/11/1997   CAD 1.39125
9/11/1997   CHF 1.4774
9/11/1997   CZK 33.6755
9/11/1997   DKK 6.8203
9/11/1997   HKD 7.7455
9/11/1997   IDR 2943
9/11/1997   JPY 119.77
9/11/1997   KWD -1
9/11/1997   MXN 7.7855
9/11/1997   NOK 7.36715
9/11/1997   NZD 1.579654
9/11/1997   PHP 32.53
9/11/1997   SEK 7.7944
9/11/1997   SGD 1.511
9/11/1997   THB 35.475
9/11/1997   TWD 28.6125
9/11/1997   ZAR 4.698
9/12/1997   AED -1
9/12/1997   AUD 1.386001
9/12/1997   CAD 1.39325
9/12/1997   CHF 1.46475
9/12/1997   CZK 33.449
9/12/1997   DKK 6.7377
9/12/1997   HKD 7.746
9/12/1997   IDR 2933
9/12/1997   JPY 120.815
9/12/1997   KWD -1
9/12/1997   MXN 7.7765
9/12/1997   NOK 7.2844
9/12/1997   NZD 1.575175
9/12/1997   PHP 32.2
9/12/1997   SEK 7.65845
9/12/1997   SGD 1.514
9/12/1997   THB 36.225
9/12/1997   TWD 28.613
9/12/1997   ZAR 4.6865
9/15/1997   AED -1
9/15/1997   AUD 1.387829
9/15/1997   CAD 1.39185
9/15/1997   CHF 1.45175
```

With a reference date of 2/19/1999, I'd like to return the following data (example shows just two currencies, actual data returned would include all currencies):

```
    AsOfDate    Currency    ExchangeRateUSD
2/8/1999    EUR 0.888968
2/9/1999    EUR 0.884956
2/10/1999   EUR 0.883275
2/11/1999   EUR 0.885152
2/12/1999   EUR 0.886682
2/15/1999   EUR 0.889957
2/16/1999   EUR 0.894454
2/17/1999   EUR 0.890234
2/18/1999   EUR 0.891107
2/19/1999   EUR 0.901266
2/8/1999    JPY 113.71
2/9/1999    JPY 114.38
2/10/1999   JPY 114.52
2/11/1999   JPY 114.3
2/12/1999   JPY 114.305
2/15/1999   JPY 115.525
2/16/1999   JPY 118.175
2/17/1999   JPY 118.895
2/18/1999   JPY 119.82
2/19/1999   JPY 120.53
```

For a reference date of 2/25/1999, I'd like to return the following data (again, actual data would show all currencies):

```
AsOfDate    Currency    ExchangeRateUSD
2/12/1999   EUR 0.886682
2/15/1999   EUR 0.889957
2/16/1999   EUR 0.894454
2/17/1999   EUR 0.890234
2/18/1999   EUR 0.891107
2/19/1999   EUR 0.901266
2/22/1999   EUR 0.906454
2/23/1999   EUR 0.910705
2/24/1999   EUR 0.91295
2/25/1999   EUR 0.904895
2/12/1999   JPY 114.305
2/15/1999   JPY 115.525
2/16/1999   JPY 118.175
2/17/1999   JPY 118.895
2/18/1999   JPY 119.82
2/19/1999   JPY 120.53
2/22/1999   JPY 120.33
2/23/1999   JPY 121.195
2/24/1999   JPY 121.88
2/25/1999   JPY 120.1
```

As you can see, the number of days covered between the start and end dates will be different depending on the reference date, so I can't use the day DATEPART within DATEADD().  Using the compound 2weeks-1day WILL get me the appropriate range though.

Is there any way to use a compound DATEPART within DATEADD() or another way to do this?

EDIT - I missed a pivotal point...I'd like to do this for multiple currencies with multiple reference dates simultaneously.  I have a table of reference dates (#referenceDates) that I'll be joining the exchange rates table (#exchangeRates) to and I'd like to use BETWEEN within a WHERE clause to pull the appropriate dates for each reference date, hence the need for compound DATEPART within DATEADD().

Comment: what you try to get 10 recent records for given date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a reference date of `2/25/1999`

```
SELECT TOP(10) *
  FROM DATA
 WHERE Currency = 'JPY'
   AND AsOfDate <= '19990225'
ORDER BY AsOfDate DESC;
```

For reference, if you actually want 2 weeks - 1 day, a naive expression:

```
DATEADD(D, +1, DATEADD(WK, -2, '19990225'))
```

But you're better to go with -13 days directly

```
DATEADD(D, -13, '19990225')
```

Or in your query (but it won't give you 10 data points if you have gaps in the days in your data):

```
SELECT *
  FROM DATA
 WHERE Currency = 'JPY'
   AND AsOfDate <= '19990225'
   AND AsOfDate >= DATEADD(D, -13, '19990225')
ORDER BY AsOfDate ASC;
```

Comment: Nice, DATEADD(dd,1,DATEADD(wk,-2,@referenceDate)) does the trick.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can get away with:

```
select top 10 *
from YourTable
where AsOfDate <= @refDate
order by AsOfDate desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/91350/2)**

```
SELECT
a.*
FROM(
SELECT TOP 10
t1.*
FROM tbl t1
WHERE t1.AsOfDate <='2/25/1999'
ORDER BY t1.AsOfDate DESC
)a
ORDER BY a.AsOfDate ASC
```

Result for 2/25/1999:

```
|                        ASOFDATE | CURRENCY | EXCHANGERATEUSD |
----------------------------------------------------------------
| February, 12 1999 00:00:00+0000 |      JPY |         114.305 |
| February, 15 1999 00:00:00+0000 |      JPY |         115.525 |
| February, 16 1999 00:00:00+0000 |      JPY |         118.175 |
| February, 17 1999 00:00:00+0000 |      JPY |         118.895 |
| February, 18 1999 00:00:00+0000 |      JPY |          119.82 |
| February, 19 1999 00:00:00+0000 |      JPY |          120.53 |
| February, 22 1999 00:00:00+0000 |      JPY |          120.33 |
| February, 23 1999 00:00:00+0000 |      JPY |         121.195 |
| February, 24 1999 00:00:00+0000 |      JPY |          121.88 |
| February, 25 1999 00:00:00+0000 |      JPY |           120.1 |
```